# Issue in installing mediapipe on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: python, software-installation, pip, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I am trying to install mediapipe on my Raspberry Pi 3B running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)` on  `ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)`.

I have created a virtual environment, `venv` and already installed `opencv-contrib-python` (4.8.1.78) and `numpy`(1.26.2).

1. I tried `pip install mediapipe` and `python -m pip install mediapipe` both of them results in this error:

```py
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
```

2. Another approach I tried was running `pip install mediapipe-rpi3` as mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe-rpi3/#description). This installs the package successfully but upon doing `import mediapipe` it results in this error:

```py
(venv) sanskar@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mediapipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/mediapipe/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/mediapipe/python/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings'
```

I am unsure how to get around these errors and install mediapipe successfully. I am also open to try a new approach or any workaround to install mediapipe.

---

**Additional Context:**

I need to use Mediapipe's pose solution (`mp.solutions.pose.Pose()`) in a python script I am trying to run on my Raspberry Pi, and for that, I need to install Mediapipe. So, If there is some way that I can somehow get the necessary files/pkg only for Pose() solution and make this script work, then I can try them as well.